# How to make synchronous call in ES java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 2.3 *(both server and client)*.

I added some indexes using below mention code:

```
private TransportClient txClient;

// client connection code
 
IndexResponse response = txClient.prepareIndex(some_values).setSource(some_value)
                          .execute().actionGet();

assert response.getId() != null;
```

**Immediately after addition**, I searched for that index using `SearchRequestBuilder`.

```
SearchResponse response = txClient.prepareSearch(some_values).setTypes(some_value)
                          .execute().actionGet();
```

I did not got the newly added indexes.

All I want to wait until all the indexes are added. How can I achieve that?

### EDIT :

After adding `.setRefresh(true)` to the `prepareIndex()` method, my problem is solved. But as far as I understand, it's not good for performance.

I did not want to refresh it immediately, I want to wait till all the indexes are created in the normal way.

Comment: any luck with my answer?

Comment: @VladislavKysliy sorry for not responding on your answer. Actually I am not working on that ES project now a days. I will try your suggestion and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `setWaitForYellowStatus()` method. For example:

```
ClusterHealthRequestBuilder healthRequest = txClient.admin().cluster().prepareHealth();
healthRequest.setIndices(newIndexName); // only request health of this index...
healthRequest.setWaitForYellowStatus();
ClusterHealthResponse healthResponse = healthRequest.execute().actionGet();
System.out.printf("status: %s%n", healthResponse.status());
// After that you checking
SearchResponse response = txClient.prepareSearch(some_values).setTypes(some_value)
                          .execute().actionGet();
```

I would highly recommend read this [topic](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/How-to-wait-for-a-CreateIndexRequest-to-really-finish-using-java-TransportClient-td4027828.html). Especially this part:

> Creating an index is an asynchronous node operation executed by the
>   master of the cluster. The cluster master node receives the creation
>   request, submits the index creation to the participating nodes, and
>   returns a response to the client. Meanwhile, depending on how busy the
>   other nodes are, they create the shards, and all shards register in
>   the cluster state for routing. When enough shards have registered, the
>   index state changes. This operation is encapsulated by an index-level
>   block. Unfortunately, Elasticsearch does not exactly know in advance
>   when the first shard will appear in the routing, so, because the
>   create index call must not hang, it returns early.

Comment: Cluster health would apply to index creation, whilst the question is specific about indexing a new document. This solution is not valid for indexing documents.

Comment: @MarcosCarceles why do you think that? did you read this? "All I want to wait until all the indexes are added. How can I achieve that?"

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realise it was addressed only to the specific case when the server was starting up, for which your answer is correct. For the general case when you want to assert that your index operations are fully completed you should use this API instead: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-indices.html#java-admin-indices-refresh

Comment: @MarcosCarceles no problem. i think you can remove downvote and add your own answer